# RoR or Sinatra Inserting into Multiple MySql Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

We have a php website that currently acts as a registration portal. I want to port this to RoR or Sinatra.

When a user signs up, they enter their name and email. The sign-up page contain some other hidden variables, including which group they belong to. Using php when they submit the form we do this:

1. insert into name, email and password into usertable
2. insert groupname and some other attributes into grouptable

We have multiple sql functions do this.

Question 1:

How do I do this in a RoR app? I can create a nested form with some hidden variables but I do not know how to insert the data in to a couple of tables? Do I have to create some kind of association?

Question 2:

How can I prevent the users from tampering with the hidden variables? If the change the group from A to B in the html and submit, I want the app to know.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the the group is in some way determined by the server (path, some random variable, something else), so, instead of passing it down to the client, store it in the session for that user when the page is generated, and read it when the response is read.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: in sinatra use session[:key_name] = "value"